# After Succesfull Click Sendkeys on the same Element gives ElementNotInteractableException

Tags: c#, selenium

When I send data to a searchfield on a listpage a ElementNotInteractableException is thrown although a click in the same field just before sending this data is succesfull, with a blinking cursor in the field as a result. How is it possible that clicking on the field is succesfull but Sendkeys not?

```
public void SearchForBranch(string branch)
{
    Driver.WaitAndClick(SearchBranch);
    SearchBranch.SendKeys(branch);
    SearchBranch.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
}
```

Zoeken



_search_









_add_

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML?

Comment: Solved it. Problem was that the WebElement I was interacting with was a Div and not the Input field.

Comment: @ KunduK I tried to post the HTML but it took a lot of time to format it

Answer (score 1):

I know the issue.
This is because the web element is in a state where it cannot click or cause any action.
Example fee: hidden or unvisible.
Use the IJavaScriptExecutor.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor driver1 = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
IWebElement resElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("g-recaptcha-response"));
driver1.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').style.display='block'");
```

If you know the javascript,it will be good example.